# iterating through a json object to get the keys as column name

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a JSON file coming from the server endpoint and it looks exactly like below. 

I want to extract the column name only and I have tried all the possible way to extract it but not getting it exactly in the way what I want.

```js
var data = {
  "data": [
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"MATTE LEAO\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"FULL SUGAR\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"LEMON\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"EXISTING\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"EXISTING\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA COCLCMPN MATELEAO MATELEAO MATELEAO X\",\"ID\":199419121,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"MATTE LEAO\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"COCA COLA\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"MATTE LEAO\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"MATTE LEAO\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"COCA COLA COMPANY\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"MATTE LEAO\",\"SERVING\":\"SINGLE SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"300 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"MATTE LEAO\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"MATE TEA\",\"Time\":\"YTD - Latest Available\",\"Value USD\":4830433.0,\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":234214.51,\"TDPs\":461.0,\"Units Sales\":4432880.0,\"Wtd Dist (Avg)\":38.42}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"TRADITIONAL TRADE\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"DIET LIPTON\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"LOW/NO CALORIE\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"PEACH\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA PEPSICO LIPTON DTLIPTON DTLIPTON X\",\"ID\":199419174,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"LIPTON\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"PEPSICO\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"DIET LIPTON\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"CAN\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"LIPTON\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"PEPSICO\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"LIPTON\",\"SERVING\":\"SINGLE SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"340 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"DIET LIPTON\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"BLACK TEA\",\"Time\":\"YTD - Latest Available\",\"Value USD\":4773.0,\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":260.66,\"TDPs\":9.0,\"Units Sales\":4370.0,\"Wtd Dist (Avg)\":2.25}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"MODERN TRADE\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"CHA LEAO\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"LOW/NO CALORIE\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"NATURAL\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA COCLCMPN CHALEAO CHALEAO CHALEAO X\",\"ID\":199419120,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"CHA LEAO\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"COCA COLA\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"CHA LEAO\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"PLASTIC BOTTLE\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"CHA LEAO\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"COCA COLA COMPANY\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"CHA LEAO\",\"SERVING\":\"MULTI SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"1500 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"CHA LEAO\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"MATE TEA\",\"Time\":\"MAT - Latest Available\",\"Value USD\":1278.0,\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":174.36,\"TDPs\":0.0,\"Units Sales\":670.0,\"Wtd Dist (Avg)\":0.0}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"MODERN TRADE\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"LOW/NO CALORIE\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA AO AO AO AO X\",\"ID\":328319978,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"NATURAL TEA\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"EBBA\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"CAN\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SERVING\":\"SINGLE SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"335 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"GREEN TEA\",\"Time\":\"YTD - Latest Available\",\"Value USD\":466.0,\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":22.9,\"TDPs\":2.0,\"Units Sales\":400.0,\"Wtd Dist (Avg)\":1.0}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"MODERN TRADE\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"LOW/NO CALORIE\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA AO AO AO AO X\",\"ID\":199418850,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"LIV\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"TECNOJUICE COMERC DE PROD.ALIM\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"CARTON\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SERVING\":\"SINGLE SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"330 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"GREEN TEA\",\"Time\":\"DECEMBER 2017\",\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":0.0}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"MODERN TRADE\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"LOW/NO CALORIE\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"LEMON\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA AO AO AO AO X\",\"ID\":199419053,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"PURITY\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"COCAMAR\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"CARTON\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SERVING\":\"MULTI SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"1000 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"GREEN TEA\",\"Time\":\"MAT - Latest Available\",\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":0.0}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"TRADITIONAL TRADE\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"LOW/NO CALORIE\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"CRANBERRY\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA AO AO AO AO X\",\"ID\":199419107,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"OUTRAS MARCAS\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"O.FAB.\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"CARTON\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SERVING\":\"SINGLE SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"1000 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"RED TEA\",\"Time\":\"MAT - Latest Available\",\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":0.0}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"LOW/NO CALORIE\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA AO AO AO AO X\",\"ID\":199419276,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"REI DO MATE\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"REI DO MATE\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"PLASTIC BOTTLE\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SERVING\":\"SINGLE SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"350 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"GREEN TEA\",\"Time\":\"YTD YA- Latest Available\",\"Value USD\":11114.0,\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":545.97,\"TDPs\":0.0,\"Units Sales\":8810.0,\"Wtd Dist (Avg)\":0.25}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"FULL SUGAR\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"NATURAL\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"LOW DISTRIBUTION\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"NEW\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA AO AO AO AO X\",\"ID\":199419265,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"REI DO MATE\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"REI DO MATE\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"PLASTIC BOTTLE\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SERVING\":\"SINGLE SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"350 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"MATE TEA\",\"Time\":\"YTD YA- Latest Available\",\"Value USD\":28365.0,\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":1375.48,\"TDPs\":1.0,\"Units Sales\":22290.0,\"Wtd Dist (Avg)\":0.2}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"MODERN TRADE\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"FULL SUGAR\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"NATURAL\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA AO AO AO AO X\",\"ID\":328319876,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"TEARAPY\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"BRASIL BEVERARES IND E COM\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"PLASTIC BOTTLE\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SERVING\":\"MULTI SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"1500 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"MATE TEA\",\"Time\":\"YTD YA- Latest Available\",\"Value USD\":532.0,\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":45.79,\"TDPs\":0.0,\"Units Sales\":170.0,\"Wtd Dist (Avg)\":0.0}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"TRADITIONAL TRADE\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"LOW/NO CALORIE\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"TANGERINE\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA AO AO AO AO X\",\"ID\":328319880,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"RIO\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"REFRIX ENVASADORA DE BEBIDAS\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"CARTON\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SERVING\":\"MULTI SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"1000 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"GREEN TEA\",\"Time\":\"MAT YA- Latest Available\",\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":0.0}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"LOW/NO CALORIE\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"LEMON\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA AO AO AO AO X\",\"ID\":199419226,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"RIO\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"REFRIX ENVASADORA DE BEBIDAS\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"CAN\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SERVING\":\"SINGLE SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"335 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"GREEN TEA\",\"Time\":\"MAT YA- Latest Available\",\"Value USD\":2909.0,\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":123.28,\"TDPs\":0.0,\"Units Sales\":2080.0,\"Wtd Dist (Avg)\":0.0}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"MODERN TRADE\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"FULL SUGAR\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"LEMON\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA AO AO AO AO X\",\"ID\":199418779,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"ICED TEA\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"BISCHOFSZELL NAHRUNGSMITTEL AG\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"CARTON\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SERVING\":\"MULTI SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"1000 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"BLACK TEA\",\"Time\":\"MAT YA- Latest Available\",\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":0.0}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"MODERN TRADE\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"MATTE LEAO\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"FULL SUGAR\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"LEMON\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"EXISTING\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"EXISTING\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA COCLCMPN MATELEAO MATELEAO MATELEAO X\",\"ID\":199418978,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"MATTE LEAO\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"COCA COLA\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"MATTE LEAO\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"PLASTIC BOTTLE\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"MATTE LEAO\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"COCA COLA COMPANY\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"MATTE LEAO\",\"SERVING\":\"MULTI SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"1500 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"MATTE LEAO\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"MATE TEA\",\"Time\":\"YTD 2YA- Latest Available\",\"Value USD\":7568924.0,\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":1288901.02,\"TDPs\":78.0,\"Units Sales\":4878930.0,\"Wtd Dist (Avg)\":73.42}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"MODERN TRADE\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"FULL SUGAR\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA AO AO AO AO X\",\"ID\":304968028,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"CAMPO LARGO\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"FAMIGLIA ZANLORENZI\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"PLASTIC BOTTLE\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SERVING\":\"MULTI SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"1350 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"MATE TEA\",\"Time\":\"MAT 2YA- Latest Available\",\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":0.0}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"MODERN TRADE\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"FULL SUGAR\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"LEMON\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"LOW DISTRIBUTION\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"NEW\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA AO AO AO AO X\",\"ID\":199419147,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"CINI\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"HUGO CINI\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"PLASTIC BOTTLE\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SERVING\":\"SINGLE SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"450 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"MATE TEA\",\"Time\":\"YTD 2YA- Latest Available\",\"Value USD\":33973.0,\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":4786.9,\"TDPs\":1.0,\"Units Sales\":60390.0,\"Wtd Dist (Avg)\":2.33}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"MODERN TRADE\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"LEAO ICE TEA\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"LOW/NO CALORIE\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"PEACH\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA COCLCMPN LEAOICTE LEAOICTE LEAOICTE X\",\"ID\":199419141,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"LEAO FUZE\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"COCA COLA\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"LEAO ICE TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"PLASTIC BOTTLE\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"LEAO ICE TEA\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"COCA COLA COMPANY\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"LEAO ICE TEA\",\"SERVING\":\"MULTI SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"1500 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"LEAO ICE TEA\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"BLACK TEA\",\"Time\":\"YTD 2YA- Latest Available\",\"Value USD\":22371.0,\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":4179.29,\"TDPs\":0.0,\"Units Sales\":15840.0,\"Wtd Dist (Avg)\":0.83}",
    "{\"COUNTRY\":\"BRAZIL\",\"INTERNATIONAL CHANNEL\":\"ALL OTHER\",\"BOTTLE CAP TYPE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"BRAND\":\"LEAO ICE TEA\",\"CAFFEINE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CALORIES\":\"FULL SUGAR\",\"CARBONATED\":\"NOT CARBONATED\",\"CHILLED\":\"AMBIENT\",\"CONCENTRATE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CSD FLAVOUR GROUP\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"ENHANCED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"FLAVOUR\":\"LEMON\",\"INNOVATION_DATE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_SCOPE\":\"NOT DEFINED\",\"INNOVATION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"INTRODUCTION_TYPE\":\"NO SALES\",\"ITEM\":\"1 BEV BEV RTDTEA SHLFSTEA COCLCMPN LEAOICTE LEAOICTE LEAOICTE X\",\"ID\":199418760,\"SDESC\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"SDESC2\":\"'- ITEM -\",\"LOCAL BRAND\":\"LEAO ICE TEA\",\"LOCAL MANUFACTURER\":\"COCA COLA\",\"LOCAL SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB BRAND\":\"LEAO ICE TEA\",\"LOCAL SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"LOCAL SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"MINERALIZED CLAIM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"NUMBER IN MULTIPACK\":\"X1\",\"PACKAGE TYPE\":\"PLASTIC BOTTLE\",\"POWDERED\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"PULP\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"REFILLABLE REUSABLE\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"GLOBAL REPORTING BRAND\":\"LEAO ICE TEA\",\"MANUFACTURER\":\"COCA COLA COMPANY\",\"SEGMENT\":\"RTD TEA\",\"TRADEMARK\":\"LEAO ICE TEA\",\"SERVING\":\"MULTI SERVE\",\"SIZE\":\"1500 ML\",\"SUB BRAND\":\"LEAO ICE TEA\",\"SUB CATEGORY\":\"BEVERAGES\",\"SUB SEGMENT\":\"SHELF STABLE TEA\",\"SUPER PREMIUM\":\"NOT AVAILABLE\",\"TYPE OF CONTENT\":\"BLACK TEA\",\"Time\":\"MAT 2YA- Latest Available\",\"Volume Sales ('000) 8oz cases\":0.0}"
  ],
  "datafileId": "Version0",
  "id": "0f74d7ee-342d-42f3-b4d7-ee342d52f389",
  "_rid": "gKJDAJ2k28EDAAAAAAAAAA==",
  "_self": "dbs/gKJDAA==/colls/gKJDAJ2k28E=/docs/gKJDAJ2k28EDAAAAAAAAAA==/",
  "_etag": "\"06002465-0000-2200-0000-5da56cdc0000\"",
  "_attachments": "attachments/",
  "_ts": 1571122396
}
var column = data["data"];
//let keys = Object.keys(data1.data);
//console.log(column[0]);
var arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(column[0]);
console.log(arrayOfKeys);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: For some reason, `data.data` is an array of strings that *represent* JSON objects, not just an array of objects. You could parse them, but I'd be inclined to fix it upstream.

Comment: What exactly is the `column name only` ??

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: can you tell me is the structure of the json is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the string data on property `data` to an object with `JSON parse`. After this you can use feature `Object.keys` to iterate and return each of the keys (names, as you called).

```
Object.keys(JSON.parse(data.data[0]))
```

Comment: A bit of explanation will be fine. Try to help people learn and understand what is happening. Just copying code without udnerstanding nothing creates the problems we see everyday on StackOverflow.

Comment: Added some context to the reply

Answer (score -1):

The reason for unable to extract is because the file received is stringified, need to be parsed to extract data

For parsing the received JSON, in this case you can use

```
console.log(Object.keys(JSON.parse(data["data"][0])));
```

Comment: he wants the column name does JSON.parse can give him the column name ?

Comment: I guess you should copy his code and try to run yours on that. You can also press the `Copy snippet to answer` and create an answer based on his code, to see that his don't works as expected.